# Why aren't css transitions firing on toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <a class="btn" href="#" id="split-me">Click Me!</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden">
  <h2>I like Nachos!</h2>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>

html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

.top {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAMAAAAp4XiDAAAAUVBMVEWFhYWDg4N3d3dtbW17e3t1dXWBgYGHh4d5eXlzc3OLi4ubm5uVlZWPj4+NjY19fX2JiYl/f39ra2uRkZGZmZlpaWmXl5dvb29xcXGTk5NnZ2c8TV1mAAAAG3RSTlNAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEAvEOwtAAAFVklEQVR4XpWWB67c2BUFb3g557T/hRo9/WUMZHlgr4Bg8Z4qQgQJlHI4A8SzFVrapvmTF9O7dmYRFZ60YiBhJRCgh1FYhiLAmdvX0CzTOpNE77ME0Zty/nWWzchDtiqrmQDeuv3powQ5ta2eN0FY0InkqDD73lT9c9lEzwUNqgFHs9VQce3TVClFCQrSTfOiYkVJQBmpbq2L6iZavPnAPcoU0dSw0SUTqz/GtrGuXfbyyBniKykOWQWGqwwMA7QiYAxi+IlPdqo+hYHnUt5ZPfnsHJyNiDtnpJyayNBkF6cWoYGAMY92U2hXHF/C1M8uP/ZtYdiuj26UdAdQQSXQErwSOMzt/XWRWAz5GuSBIkwG1H3FabJ2OsUOUhGC6tK4EMtJO0ttC6IBD3kM0ve0tJwMdSfjZo+EEISaeTr9P3wYrGjXqyC1krcKdhMpxEnt5JetoulscpyzhXN5FRpuPHvbeQaKxFAEB6EN+cYN6xD7RYGpXpNndMmZgM5Dcs3YSNFDHUo2LGfZuukSWyUYirJAdYbF3MfqEKmjM+I2EfhA94iG3L7uKrR+GdWD73ydlIB+6hgref1QTlmgmbM3/LeX5GI1Ux1RWpgxpLuZ2+I+IjzZ8wqE4nilvQdkUdfhzI5QDWy+kw5Wgg2pGpeEVeCCA7b85BO3F9DzxB3cdqvBzWcmzbyMiqhzuYqtHRVG2y4x+KOlnyqla8AoWWpuBoYRxzXrfKuILl6SfiWCbjxoZJUaCBj1CjH7GIaDbc9kqBY3W/Rgjda1iqQcOJu2WW+76pZC9QG7M00dffe9hNnseupFL53r8F7YHSwJWUKP2q+k7RdsxyOB11n0xtOvnW4irMMFNV4H0uqwS5ExsmP9AxbDTc9JwgneAT5vTiUSm1E7BSflSt3bfa1tv8Di3R8n3Af7MNWzs49hmauE2wP+ttrq+AsWpFG2awvsuOqbipWHgtuvuaAE+A1Z/7gC9hesnr+7wqCwG8c5yAg3AL1fm8T9AZtp/bbJGwl1pNrE7RuOX7PeMRUERVaPpEs+yqeoSmuOlokqw49pgomjLeh7icHNlG19yjs6XXOMedYm5xH2YxpV2tc0Ro2jJfxC50ApuxGob7lMsxfTbeUv07TyYxpeLucEH1gNd4IKH2LAg5TdVhlCafZvpskfncCfx8pOhJzd76bJWeYFnFciwcYfubRc12Ip/ppIhA1/mSZ/RxjFDrJC5xifFjJpY2Xl5zXdguFqYyTR1zSp1Y9p+tktDYYSNflcxI0iyO4TPBdlRcpeqjK/piF5bklq77VSEaA+z8qmJTFzIWiitbnzR794USKBUaT0NTEsVjZqLaFVqJoPN9ODG70IPbfBHKK+/q/AWR0tJzYHRULOa4MP+W/HfGadZUbfw177G7j/OGbIs8TahLyynl4X4RinF793Oz+BU0saXtUHrVBFT/DnA3ctNPoGbs4hRIjTok8i+algT1lTHi4SxFvONKNrgQFAq2/gFnWMXgwffgYMJpiKYkmW3tTg3ZQ9Jq+f8XN+A5eeUKHWvJWJ2sgJ1Sop+wwhqFVijqWaJhwtD8MNlSBeWNNWTa5Z5kPZw5+LbVT99wqTdx29lMUH4OIG/D86ruKEauBjvH5xy6um/Sfj7ei6UUVk4AIl3MyD4MSSTOFgSwsH/QJWaQ5as7ZcmgBZkzjjU1UrQ74ci1gWBCSGHtuV1H2mhSnO3Wp/3fEV5a+4wz//6qy8JxjZsmxxy5+4w9CDNJY09T072iKG0EnOS0arEYgXqYnXcYHwjTtUNAcMelOd4xpkoqiTYICWFq0JSiPfPDQdnt+4/wuqcXY47QILbgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
    background-color: #3498db;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,.50);
    transition: 25s top ease-in;
}

.bottom {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.45);
    transition: .25s top ease-in;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.slide-up {
    top: -50%;
    transition: .25s all ease-in;
}

.slide-down {
    top: 50%;
    transition: .25s all ease-in;
}

.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -5;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.hidden h2 {
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
    color: #3498db;
}

.btn {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    height: 85px;
    width: 145px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3498db;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: .25s all;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #3498db,0px 0 0 10px white,0px 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5),0px 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    transition: .25s all ease-in;
}

.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #3498db,0px 0 0 20px white,0px 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5),0px 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    transition: .25s all ease-in;
}



$('#split-me').click(function(){
      $('.top').toggleClass('slide-up');
      $('.bottom').toggleClass('slide-down');
  });
```

Code: http://codepen.io/DuzAwe/pen/RazYYW

On click, the tags are toggled to reveal the hidden area creating a split effect. But the transitions on the classes are providing no easing?

Am I using them wrong?

Comment: May be you should use browser specific attributes like  `  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;`

Comment: transition is the standard now for modern browsers. Not targeting older ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are animating the top property, but in the `.top` class there is no top, property, so there is no animation, same for the `.bottom` class.

Check it here:
http://codepen.io/tomsarduy/pen/MyMqdq

Comment: Thank you knew it would be something like this.